# Should I use exception handling in a program where all exceptions lead to termination?

Tags: c++, exception

I am currently developing a simulation tool. The tool is not interactive. All possible exceptions will be due to programming errors (during development) or corrupted input data. If an exception occurs, the program has to terminate since it simply makes no sense to run on.

So I have 2 options:

1. Use C++ exception handling. Pro: I get a stack trace upon crash when debugging. Contra: **Serious** (?) performance overhead.
2. Call an error function that terminates the program. Pro: Fast and simple. Contra: No stack trace.

Question: How bad is the impact on performance? Some of the exceptions could originate from very time critical functions.

And please let me know if there is anything fundamentally wrong in my considerations.

Comment: How did you come up with ***Serious** performance overhead*? Typical implementations only introduce overhead when an exception is thrown, not when the non-exceptional path is taken.

Comment: @Praetorian: There's also some overhead due to reduced optimization possibilities (That's one big reason for `noexcept`). Still not really serious though.

Comment: Are you sure you can't get a core-dump on `abort()`?

Comment: Have a single try/catch in main and get your stack trace

Comment: The only way to know about overhead is to perform a test and time it. I am not sure why @Deduplicator thinks there will be extra overhead (if you need an if to test before a throw you also need a test before a call to abort, both will prevent optimizations in the same way). Exceptions in the general case have no overhead when an exception is not thrown. The extra overhead when thrown is not really a concern when you do throw it because you will be terminate the application.

Comment: For tracking programming level errors use `assert()`.

Comment: @LokiAstari: If a function can possibly throw an exception, that inhibits some otherwise perfectly fine code-transformations, and means all the handling code+data mst be stored. While the latter all can be ignored completely on the non-exception-path, the former is on all paths. Anyway, [@doc](http://stackoverflow.com/u/205955) is right about `assert()` being the right tool for finding programming errors. (`abort` only if they should not disappear even in production code. Maybe add a macro `verify`...)

Comment: If errors are unrecoverable then using exceptions does not make much sense. Ideally exceptions should be used with transactional model, when you can revert all the changes made by try-catch block, but this is not always possible.

Answer (score 1):

As @doc suggests I would probably use `assert` to track input-agnostic programming errors. Then I would use exceptions for input-related errors. Not only is that exactly what exceptions are for, if you ever happen to encounter a type of input error from which you can recover the exception framework is already there for you.